# Passing function as parameter in c# works but not in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

So I have the following line of code in c# to register AutoMapper with SimpleInjector:

`container.Register(() => config.CreateMapper(container.GetInstance));`

For context, `config.CreateMapper()` looks like this:

`public IMapper CreateMapper(Func<Type, object> serviceCtor);`

While `container.GetInstance` looks like this:

`public object GetInstance(Type serviceType);`

The first line of code I posted works in C# because `config.CreateMapper` takes in a function that takes a type of `Type` and returns a type of `object`. Exactly what `container.GetInstance` does.

When I try to do this same line in VB, as:

`container.Register(Function() config.CreateMapper(container.GetInstance))`

It gives an error `Type arguments for 'Public Function Container.GetInstance(Of TService)()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying type arguments explicitly`. It is giving this error because `container.GetInstance` has an overload that looks like this:

`public TService GetInstance<TService>() where TService : class;`

Why does the VB try to use the wrong overload of `GetInstance` and how can I force it to use the correct one?

Comment: () are optional, right now it's trying to call the method GetInstance without any parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AddressOf` for getting function reference.

```
container.Register(Function() config.CreateMapper(AddressOf container.GetInstance))
```

In C# function with parenthesis executes it, function without parenthesis will return reference to the function.

In VB.NET parenthesis in function are optional - function will be executed anyway. So for referencing a function you should use `AddressOf` operator.
[AddressOf Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/addressof-operator)

Comment: Thank you! Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `AddressOf` keyword before the function parameter to define this as Parameter as function pointer.

`AddressOf` ist the same as `@` keyword in C#. The keyword is implicit used in your c# sample.